# Rendering issues with IE7 in quirks mode

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

I have developed a website which works fine in all browsers except IE7 as reported by some users. In IE7 it is completely broken up.

Unfortunately I do not have access to any machine with IE7. Hence I installed developer toolbar on my IE8 and tried to view the site with compatibility mode set to IE7| IE7 Standards.

The site was working fine. When I set it to IE7 | IE7 Quirks mode however I could see that the site was broken.

What is the simplest way to fix this issue? Is there any way I can force the browser to render my website in IE7 standards mode always ?

Answer (score 1):

Quirks mode in IE is usually triggered by a lack of (or incorrect) doctype.

Check that your doctype is valid. This should prevent it from going into quirks mode.

If you're not sure what to do, add the following to the top of your html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know of this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

But I'm not sure if it helps in your case. Maybe it's best to see what's causing the problem and solve that in a browser-indepent way.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that. It is due to some exceptions that are raised in the YUI framework code that I am using.