# style difference in ie and chrome?

Tags: html, css

this is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div id="div1" style="float: left;height: 200px;border:1px solid red; ">1</div> 
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div id="div2" style="border:1px solid red;margin-top:20px;background-color: #FFF; ">2</div> 
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

in **Chrome** `margin-top` is enabled , div1 and div2 Apart 20px; 
but in **IE8** ,  div1 and div2 are always keep together。

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzgGz/)

Comment: add semicolon for statement end...`style="clear:both;"` because i had solved this before by adding this...hope this will work for you too

Comment: Tried it in IE8 and it looks fine to me.

Comment: Confirm whether IE loads your page in Quirks mode or compatibility mode. This may cause layout differences like this. Press F12 in IE to get the dev tools which will tell you the browser mode. If in the wrong mode, there are plenty of answers elsewhere on SO that will help. Eg [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111775/rendering-issues-with-ie7-in-quirks-mode/6112321#6112321).

Comment: @Spudley well, I upvoted your comment as it can be a possibility, but the above should work well, I don't see any unsupported properties used ...

Comment: did you add <!doctype> ?

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Quirks mode changes how margins work, so it may be relevant given that the question is about margins. However, it's difficult to give a better suggestion as the question doesn't include enough detail to properly diagnose or replicate the issue.

Comment: @Spudley yea, this question is unanswerable unless further details are provided

Comment: use `float:left;` sor second div too. check this http://jsfiddle.net/SzgGz/1/

Comment: @Spudley  yea , it's good when i changed model to `Quirks mode` or `ie7 Standars mode` . but `ie8 Standars mode` also render like before. and `ie8 Standars mode` is default mode ..

Comment: @imsiso thx ,is worked,but is there another way? because i dont want the  second div float

Comment: @Szerémi Attila  i change my code in original text , now you may be can see the diff in ie8 :)

Comment: why? you would mind explain more?'

Comment: I must confess that I'm viewing this in IE10, but in IE8 mode.
And it still looks fine in IE8 even with the doctype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can `float:left` in second div too.

and with adding a div in the second div you can disable aspects of floated div check http://jsfiddle.net/SzgGz/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="div1" style="float: left;height: 200px;border:1px solid red; ">1</div> 
    <div style="float:left; clear:both"></div>
    <div id="div2" style="margin-top:20px; float:left; width:100%;"><div style="border:1px solid red;background-color: #FFF;">2</div></div> 
</div>
```